Another boy kicked from party story
I remember parts of it... he is a simple boy, not looking for revenge... does odd jobs ... starts with cleaning a disaster kitchen, then in another room cures a princess of a curse.  Then digs a tunnel through a mountain, while also digging down 10 kilometers to find the rare mineral... THEN fills the whole back in... all in a single day.
Watched a YouTube recap of it, and now I can not find the video!

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

mostly black and white

This is The Unaware Atelier Master.

One day, Kurt, a kind-hearted boy, is suddenly kicked out of the Hero's Party for being "useless". He finds that his aptitude for weapons, magic, and all other combat-related skills is the lowest rank, so he takes odd-jobs repairing the castle walls and digging for minerals to make a living, where his exceptional abilities are immediately revealed. He proves to be skillful in cooking, building, mining, crafting magical tools--in fact, his aptitude for every skill unrelated to combat had an SSS-ranking!

The order of events is a bit different, I suspect due to the youtube recap. His first job, as mentioned in the synopsis, is repairing the castle walls. After that he helps a woman out with digging for valuable ores - this is where the "digging 10km" part in the question comes from.

This includes digging through the mountain, leaving a tunnel.
Some time after that he interviews with an atelier; their kitchen happens to be a disaster, so he quickly cleans it up and makes food. Secretly staying at the atelier is a princess who has been cursed; after fixing the kitchen he makes her some food that cures her.

